# Ionic 4, how to reduce the height of ionic-segment-button

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have the following code for a scrollable segment :

```
<ion-segment mode="md" scrollable >
  <ion-segment-button mode="md" *ngFor="let category of categories" value={{category}} (click)="FilterCateg(category)" >
    {{ category }}
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

How can I change the `height` of the `ion-segment/ ion-segment-button`.  Currently defaulting to `50px`.  I've tried setting `height` in the `CSS` but no effect.  Found `SASS variables $segment-button-md-height and $segment-button-md-line-height` but can't find their equivalent in `Ionic 4`

Comment: why not use the height directly?

Comment: Setting height for ion-segment-button in the CSS doesn't work.  Remains the same height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**page.scss**

`ion-segment-button` - is take `min-height 50px` in `md mode` `default`

you given `height` only in your button then only `2px` height reduce
because `min-height` is `50px` default so,

and you use `min-height` only in your button then no changes in heights

so use `height` and `min-height` both

**example given below :**

```
ion-segment-button{
    min-height: 30px; //Depends on you
    height: 30px; //Depends on you
}
```

Comment: Why both min-height and height? Why exactly 30px? Please add explanations to your "answer".